# Is this proof regarding projectors (linear algebra) correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $f: V\to V$ a projector. Let $S\subseteq V$ be a subspace such that $\text{Im}(f)\subseteq S$. Prove that $\text{Im}(f)=S$ if and only if $\ker(f)\cap S=\{0\}$.

I've been thinking about this problem for a while and I think I came up with a solution, but I would like to know if is correct and well justified.

$\Rightarrow)$ Given that $\text{Im}(f)=S$, we can use the properties of the projector to prove that $\ker(f)\cap S=\{0\}$. Since $f$ is a projector, we know that $\ker(f)\cap\text{Im}(f)=\{0\}$, and since $\text{Im}(f)=S$, we have $\ker(f)\cap S=\{0\}$, proving this part.

$\Leftarrow)$ Given that $\text{Im}(f)\subseteq S$, then is valid that $\dim(\text{Im}(f))\le\dim(S)$. Also, given that $\ker(f)\cap S=\{0\}$, then $\ker(f)\oplus S\subseteq V$, since both subspaces are in direct sum, so we have:

$$\begin{align}
\dim(\ker(f)\oplus S) &\le \dim(V) \\
\dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(S) &\le \dim(V) \\
\dim(S) &\le \dim(V) - \dim(\ker(f))
\end{align}$$

Mixing the two inequalities, with the fact that $\ker(f)\oplus\text{Im}(f)=V$, since $f$ is a projector, we get the following chain:

$$\begin{align}
\dim(\text{Im}(f))\ \le\ &\dim(S)\ \le\ \dim(V)-\dim(\ker(f)) \\
\dim(\text{Im}(f)) + \dim(\ker(f))\ \le\ &\dim(S)+\dim(\ker(f))\ \le\ \dim(V) \\
\dim(\ker(f)\oplus\text{Im}(f))\ \le\ &\dim(\ker(f)\oplus S)\ \le\ \dim(V) \\
\dim(V)\ \le\ &\dim(\ker(f)\oplus S)\ \le\ \dim(V)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $\dim(\ker(f)\oplus S)=\dim(V)$. So we can finish this part of the proof by doing the following:

$$\begin{align}
\dim(V) &= \dim(V) \\
\dim(\ker(f)\oplus\text{Im}(f)) &= \dim(\ker(f)\oplus S) \\
\dim(\ker(f))+\dim(\text{Im}(f)) &= \dim(\ker(f))+\dim(S) \\
\dim(\text{Im}(f)) &= \dim(S)
\end{align}$$

So, given that $\ker(f)\cap S=\{0\}$, we have proved that $\text{Im}(f)=S$.

Is this argument valid? Should I be more precise? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your dimension argument for the second part is overly complicated and hard to follow. If $v\in S$, then we know $v=x+y$ where $x\in\ker f$ and $y\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$. But since $\mathrm{Im}(f)\subseteq S$, this means
$$x=v-y\in\ker(f)\cap S=0$$
so $v=y\in\mathrm{Im}(f)$.

Comment: Overly complicated it may be, but the question here is still about Diego's argument.

Comment: @311411 Indeed it is. You can consider my answer as falling under the category of "any advice" pertaining to the OP's argument which he may appreciate.